# Strange bug C++ 11 template class

Tags: c++, c++11

All compiles well. But the output contains a strange error I do not understand. Would be great if someone could help me with that.

main():

```
vector<PointGeneric<float>> v(3);

for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
   v[i] = {(float)(i*1.1), (float)(i*0.9)};
   cout << "1: v[" << i <<"] = " << v[i] << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
  cout << "2: v[" << i <<"] = " << v[i] << endl;
```

Output:

```
1: v[0] = (0.000000, 0.000000)
1: v[1] = (1.100000, 0.900000)
1: v[2] = (2.200000, 1.800000)

2: v[2] = (2.200000, 1.800000)
2: v[2] = (2.200000, 1.800000)
2: v[2] = (2.200000, 1.800000)
```

Template Class: (not my own, taken from "svg-curve-lib" library on github and very slightly modified; in the original context all works well)

```
template <typename Tx = float, typename Ty = Tx>
struct PointGeneric 
{   
    public:     
      struct x_getter;
      struct y_getter;

      x_getter x{this};
      y_getter y{this};

      PointGeneric() : PointGeneric { 0, 0} {}
      PointGeneric(Tx x, Ty y) : x(this), y(this), _x{x}, _y{y} {};

 ...

   private:
     Tx _x;
     Ty _y;
};
```

x_getter - struct:

```
template <typename Tx = float, typename Ty = Tx>
struct PointGeneric<Tx, Ty>::x_getter
{
   public:
      x_getter(PointGeneric *t): thisPointer{t} {};
      operator Tx() const {return this->thisPointer->_x;};
  private:
     PointGeneric<Tx, Ty>* thisPointer;
};
```

Comment: What is the bug? Did expect different output? Which output and why? Can you make a [mcve] on some online compiler site like [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)?

Comment: Your output shows `2: v[2]` three times. This I can not reproduce with the code given. Did you faithfully reproduce the second loop?

Comment: Throw this code away. `x_getter` etc is totally useless syntactic sugar. Adds nothing but bloat.

Comment: The bug is that when I for the second time use cout on the same vector I get a different output (three times the last element of the vector). That has something to do with the x_getter struct. When I remove the latter and remove the x(this) and y(this) the bug is also removed. But the problem is the x_getter struct is needed to keep the original code of the library running. Therefore I cannot just remove this code. I would like to know: why the original author used this kind of code and why it leads to the error observed.

Comment: As WorldSEnder already mentioned, the output can't be the output of the given code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in the code shown, `PointGeneric` doesn't have a user-defined copy constructor or assignment operator, and neither does `x_getter`. Implicitly-defined versions would make it so that, after

```
PointGeneric<float> source;
PointGeneric<float> dest = source;
```

you'll have `dest.x.thisPointer` point to `source`, not to `dest` (and similarly for `dest.y`; and mutatis mutandis for assignment).

In your example, you have

```
v[i] = {(float)(i*1.1), (float)(i*0.9)};
```

Here, `source` is a temporary, destroyed at the semicolon, leaving `v[i].x.thisPointer` a dangling pointer. I presume (though it's not shown) that the expression `cout << v[i]` ends up calling `v[i].x.operator float()`, which in turn attempts to deference `thisPointer`, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior.